# Failed to sent file but able to housekeep

Tags: vbscript

Sorry as I do not know how to describe my problem due to my lack of knowledge. Please guide whenever necessary.

#### Process Flow

My text files are kept in a folder (folder1). My program (**upload.vbs**) was scheduled to look for the text files in folder1 and send it to the website through **CURL**. Then the program will run a batch file (**moveFile.bat**) to move the text files to another folder (something like housekeeping concept)

#### Problems

Currently I noticed that all my files were not sent. I suspect it is due to the way my program works. As my program call the CURL command prompt, I have another function to move files from the folder1 to another folder (something like housekeeping concept). I commented the FileMoving function and it works fine but I want this function.

Is it because due to the CURL command prompt is still running in the background (not yet finish read the files) but the files has been moved? If yes how to solve this?

---

Below is my **upload.vbs**

```
Option Explicit 
startprocess

Sub startprocess()
    Dim oFS1,objFolder,colFiles,objFile
    Set oFS1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = oFS1.GetFolder("Z:\folder1")
    Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

    For Each objFile In colFiles
        if lcase(oFS1.GetExtensionName(objfile))="txt" then
        UploadFile("Z:\folder1\" & objFile.Name)
        end if
    Next

    FileMoving  
End Sub

Sub FileMoving()
    Dim oShell 
    Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    oShell.Run "moveFile.bat",0,false
End Sub

Sub UploadFile(FileName)
    Dim oShell 
    Set oShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    oShell.Run "curl -k -U username:password -x 10.200.1.6:3127 -b edo.txt -F df=" &  FileName & " -F ""dt=ASN"" -F send=Send ""https://suppliers.somegroup.com/edo/dataexchange/uprog.jsp""" ,0,false
End Sub
```

Below is my **moveFile.bat**

```
COPY Z:\folder1\*.txt Y:\backup\*.txt
DEL Z:\folder1\*.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
oShell.Run "curl ... " , 0, false
```

passes false (= don't wait) to the [.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) method.

See:

> bWaitOnReturn Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script
>   should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to
>   the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution
>   halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code
>   returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method
>   returns immediately after starting the program, automatically
>   returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).